# getTimezoneOffset is different when i create a date with a timestamp

Tags: javascript, timezone

In my browser (firefox), i do this simple code :

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
new Date(1444824485080).getTimezoneOffset();
```

The first line return -60. I'm french so this is my timezone. But the second line returns -120. How is this possible ? I believe 1444824485080 is just a timestamp (milliseconds since 1st January 1970). How it can influence the timezone of the date created with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That timestamp falls on 14 October 2015, when France is on Central European Summer Time - which carries on offset of UTC+2.  Today, 11 December 2015, Summer Time is not in effect, so the standard Central European Time offset of UTC+1 is used.

This is the nature of time zones, especially those with daylight saving time.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and also read [the dst tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) so you can understand the impact.

The [visualization here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/france/paris) should also help.

Comment: Thanks for the light on this one.

Comment: No problem.  Just remember "Time Zone != Offset" - which will help remind you that offsets can fluctuate within each time zone.  Timestamp is indeed influential to determine the correct offset.